# SSH very slow log in after changing sshd_config, even on LAN

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, lan

I am trying to get my home server to be ssh-able from the internet.

Initially (before touching any config files, just doing `apt-get install openssh-server` i was able to connect to in while on my local LAN very quickly (basically instantly). I did `ssh username@localIP` and it prompted for my password immediately and I could log in.

I edited the `sshd_config` file to the following (from the defaults):

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding no
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

These were the initial states of the lines I changed in the file above:

```
LogLevel INFO
PermitRootLogin without-password
#PasswordAuthentication yes
X11Forwarding yes
#Banner /etc/issue.net
```

I saved these and did `sudo service ssh restart` and exited and tried to log in with `username@localIP` but for some reason the log in takes forever. Once i am logged in the connection seems very fast (which it should since its on my LAN).
What's odd is that it takes forever to log in even if i don't go through my domain name.

Next i forwarded port 22 to my servers static IP address and tried to do `username@example.com` and the log in was even slower. It took about 2 minutes to connect to the server.  And when i am connected it will randomly freeze and never work until i terminate the session manually by closing my terminal and reconnecting. Sometimes it wont ever connect at all it just hangs after i enter `ssh username@example.com`.

but if i do `ping example.com` all the packets seem to be coming back very quickly with an average ping time of 10ms.

Are my config settings messed up somehow? I tried to revert everything to how it was before and restart the ssh server but it still takes forever to log in even when i do `username@localIP@`.

So far I only have one user (besides root obviously) on the server and i manually copied the rsa key id_rsa.pub from my client machine to file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. I had to manually create both the folder `.ssh` and the file but it seems to work and not prompt me for a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the config:

```
UseDNS no
```

[This will cause the SSH server to *not* resolve login attempts via DNS.](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#3.3)

Comment: but then how can i use example.com to access the server if i cant use a DNS lookup. Isn't DNS required to use example.com to convert it to my external IP?

Comment: This doesn't affect DNS of the system, it only affects the SSH logging system by not doing reverse DNS look ups of the client trying to connect. So when you `ssh example.com`, the server gets your IP (say 192.168.1.2) and then tries to do a reverse lookup of your client IP (the 192 address), and that's what takes the time. The `UseDNS` option is mostly for logging purposes.

Comment: WOW! That changed everything! It's so fast now! Can you explain what you mean by "its used for logging"? where can i go to learn about reverse lookups and why did it affect it so much?

Comment: when you attempt to connect to an SSH server, it logs the IP of who tried to connect. When it logs the IP, if `UseDNS` is `yes` then it tries to do a reverse DNS lookup on the IP .. same thing as if you did `host 192.168.1.2` on Linux/Unix .. Reverse DNS is just that .. when you `ping www.google.com` you get back the IP of `www.google.com` (`216.58.217.206` as an example) .. but if you want to find out `who's at 216.58.217.206` you'd do a reverse DNS (kind of like a reverse phone look up) which then tell you `216.58.217.206 is www.google.com` ..

Comment: [More info on reverse DNS lookup from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)

Comment: got it! so when i ssh into the server it logs the client IP address and then tries to do a reverse DNS on the client machine to figure out who's trying to come in? and that just happens to take a long time?

Does this mean i can't log who attempts to connect to the server if UseDNS is off? Or I just can't get their domain name (if they have one)?

Comment: uh oh, im getting an issue where it freezes after i stay logged in for a while... i cant unfreeze it so i have to close the terminal window and log back in manually.... What is going on

Comment: Right, it can take a long time if the client IP trying to connect doesn't resolve (it takes a while because it times out). The `UseDNS` doesn't affect the logging itself, just that it will only log the IP that attempted to connect instead of the domain name for the IP .. as for it freezing after staying logged in, that's another issue (might be related to your config, but not to the `UseDNS`)  .. ?

Comment: i believe its ssh is being dropped from inactivity, i must learn to set some keepAlive signals. Thanks for the help with the login problems.